# missing ) after argument list in views\home.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: html, ejs, anchor

This the code which shows the error:

```
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>
        <%= startingContent; %>
    </p>
    <%   posts.forEach(function (posts) {%>
        <h1>
            <%=posts.pTitle;%>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <%=posts.pBody.substring(0,100) + " ..."%>
                <a href="/posts/<%= posts.pTitle%>">Read More</a>
        </p>


        <%- include ( "partials/footer"); -%>
```

The header file includes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Daily Journal</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <p class="navbar-brand">DAILY JOURNAL</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- 6 -->
                <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="/contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
```

The footer file includes:

```
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="footer-padding"></div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Made </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

And the Error its shows:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in \views\home.ejs while compiling ejs

I am not able to debug this error.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it seems you never close this

```
<%   posts.forEach(function (posts) {%>
```

you should have a line that ends it.

```
<% }) %>
```